# How to change the color theme per post?

Tags: posts, themes, front-end

A client of mine wants to be able to choose between a dark and a light theme each time he publishes a post. What's the best way to change the color of a theme per post?

I thought in creating a taxonomy called "template" and within that two options: "dark" and "light". However, I dont know yet how to change the whole theme depending on the taxonomy if I load the single post. And I cant think of a smarter way to do it in Archive pages.

Is there a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: Use [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) or Post Meta which will allow the user to manage the color per post. Whether you want to do this via drop-down or predefined colors or a colorpicker is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree to the comment by Howdy_McGee to use Custom Fields. A nice implementation would be possible with [`add_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

---

### 1. Approach: The body_class Filter

So for example, you could let him enter a custom field `'color-scheme'`. In the next step, you could simply hook into the `'body_class'`-filter and add another class to the `<body>`-tag depending on what is saved in the current custom field:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'chg_color_by_post' );
function chg_color_by_post( $classes ){
    if( is_singular() ){
        $color_scheme = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'color-scheme', true );
        if( $color_scheme == 'dark' )
            $classes[] = 'dark';
        if( $color_scheme == 'light' )
            $classes[] = 'light';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Now you are free to go with your CSS stylesheet. For example:

```
.dark{
  background: #000;
}

.dark p{
  color: #fff;
}

.light{
  background:#fff;
}

.light p{
  color: #000;
}
```

Of course for this solution, you have to use the [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function in the `<body>`-Tag.

---

### 2. Approach: Enqueue different styles depending on custom field

Another solution based on the custom field would be to enqueue different styles depending on the value set in the custom field:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'change_style_by_post' );
function change_style_by_post(){
    if( is_singular() ){
        $color_scheme = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'color-scheme', true );
        if( $color_scheme == 'dark' )
            wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-dark', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-dark.css' );
        if( $color_scheme == 'light' )
            wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-light', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-light.css' );
    }
}
```

With this approach you are more flexible and you can organise your CSS code in different files. You could even remove all CSS Styles (by deregistering them, see for this [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style)) and register only styles for the specific color scheme.

Comment: **Wow, this is EXACTLY what I was searching for.** I didn't know how to add this class to the body. How would you display the archive page? In a case there are several posts loaded one below another and each of them has a different color?

Comment: well in this case i wouldnt apply it, this is why i use is_singular() to apply the stylesheets only on single pages.

Comment: I figured it out that its actually very easy to apply your code to archive pages too. The only thing needed is: `if( is_singular() || is_archive() ){`

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the difference in details, but I would guess the two themes aren't any, or at least much, different outside of color scheme.

My approach would be simply to implement one (or both) color schemes as secondary CSS stylesheets to enqueue conditionally and stick with same theme for both of them.